# Is it wrong to add multiple meta keywords and description occurrence in head?

Tags: html, seo

Can I add the keyword and description meta names multiple times? Will it affect SEO anyway?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="keywords" content="about our website" >
<meta name="description" content="about our website" >
<meta name="description" content="Site meta description" >
<meta name="keywords" content="site,meta,keywords" >
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this. What do you think the benefit is?

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine only the last one of each would be used.

Comment: Or only the first one. It's invalid code so search engines could do anything

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's believed to affect click-through rate; here is a website that talks about their success in using multiple Meta Descriptions:

http://explicitly.me/dynamic-meta-descriptions-for-seo

Comment: That example is about using a single meta description but extending the content in it. Not what is being done here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but there is most likely no value in it.

There could be a risk it triggers some sort of low quality or spam flag.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11488471/952234) it is said that that is valid. In fact, I see no prohibitions in w3 specification of [meta](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/meta.name.html) (though there could be some deeper things I'm not aware of).

I'm not sure what will the correct answer with keywords (at least they are not shown as output to users) be, but with description that is probably a very wrong thing to do.

http://www.google.com/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf

It's written that description is what users see on search engine output results. So with multiple descriptions you will probably get not what you wanted, but some arbitrary value depending on indexer behaviour.